# MS Access and auto-compete

Tags: ms-access, autocomplete

Suppose I have two table now

```
Table A{ID,Description}
Table B{ID,QTY}
```

When user enter column ID in Table B, it is expected that a auto-complete box is shown according to the column ID in table A. Can MS access do this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do this with the Combo in Access.

When you're viewing the combo in design view, look at the Property Sheet window. You should be able to set the "Control Source" to allow you to store whatever value the user selects into the correct field (in this case the ID field in Table B).

Next, change the Property called Row Source Type to show Table/Query. Then go to the Row Source Property and click on the three dotted button to create a new Lookup Query using Table A.

Last of all, you'll need to change the properties to display 2 columns. Set the width to something like 0";2" so that you won't be displaying the ID, only the description.

That should be all you need to do to make this work.

Comment: Thank in advance. But I want to show the whole table B and user can this "combobox" in every row of table B

Comment: You should be able to do that if you put your combo on a DataSheet view form or a Continuous Form.